# symfony inline asset with assetic

Tags: javascript, css, symfony, assets, assetic

I have the following code based on Symfony2 docs:

```
    {% block javascripts %}

        {% javascripts filter="?jsqueeze" output="js/app.js"
            "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/assets/js/one.js"
            "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/assets/js/two.js" %}
            <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
        {% endjavascripts %}

    {% endblock %}
```

which works like charm.

What I want to do, is instead of

```
<script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
```

use something like:

```
<script> ... inline asset contents here ... </script>
```

I tried assetic docs as well as digging around AsseticTokenParser and AsseticNode classes, but couldn't find a variable which references to the actual filepath instead of url.

Normally I do it with css rather than js, but it should be the same concept.

thanks!

Comment: if it won't work with assetic, try the tiwg function `include`

Comment: `include` function will include a file without processing it, applying filters and/or combining multiple files into one.

Answer (score 2):

In production mode, symfony generates a link to a static file, which can be included directly into the template. This file needs to be generated with something like:

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

In dev mode, there is no static file generated which can be included. The asset_url contains an url which will call symfony controller which will in turn generate required js/css files on the fly. Aparently it is very easy to include the output of a controller in symfony:

```
{% render asset_url %}
```

To answer my own question, one could write a twig extension, which would include a static file or forward request to `render` method depending on wether it has been called in prod or dev mode.

I will update this page if/when I write an extension like this.

Another option is not to use dev mode of assetic and always generate static css/js files on the fly with:

```
php app/console assetic:watch
```

Then a simple `include` would work.

I wish there was an out of the box method in Symfony to get this common task done.